# Dropzone js posts code in dropzone box on file upload

Tags: javascript, dropzone

I am using Dropzone JS to try and implement file uploads. I followed their documentation exactly and everything works great until it's time to upload files. If I try to upload files it stacks the images vertically along with a check mark in a circle and an x in a circle, instead of arranging it the way it was arranged in Dropzone js. Any idea why it's doing this?

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
<button  type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>

#dropzone{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 30%;
    color: #c5c5c5;
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

Comment: This is going to be almost impossible to figure out unless you can provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just set up a blank demo and it works for me. You didn't mention - are you using `dropzone.css`? Is that and the styles you've shown above the *only* styling on the page?

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed it. Turns out I forgot to hook up dropzone css. Thanks